# In a ring $A$, $x^2 = 0$ implies $x=0$ for any $x$ in $A$. Show that if $a \in A$ satisfies $a^3=a$ then $2a$ is in the center of $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ be a ring such that for any $x \in A, x^2=0$ implies $x=0$.  Show that if $a \in A$ satisfies $a^3=a$ then $2a$ is in the center of $A$.

I have no idea how to use the $x^2=0$ implies $x=0$ thing. My progress is as follows: note that if $a^3=a$ then $6a = 0$.

Denote by $B$ the set of $a$'s in $A$ for which $a^3=a$. I suspect that $B$ actually induces a subring. First of all, $B$ is closed under taking inverses: if $a^3=a$ then $(-a)^3 = - (a^3) = -a$ so $-a \in A$. Also $B$ is closed under addition: if $a \in B$ then $(2a)^3 = 8a^3 = 8a = 2a; (3a)^3 = 27a^3 = 3a$ and $4a = - 2a, 5a = -a$.

Let's say this actually induces a subring. Then the subring is of characteristic at most $6$, so it is of characteristic $1,2,3$ or $6$. If it is of characteristic $1$ or $2$ it is trivial that $2B$ is in the center of $A$. Otherwise I dont know how to proceed.

Edit: indeed I don't think this forms a subring. I proved it: here is a quick outline: Since the ring is reduced, any idempotent element is central. If $a=a^3$ then $a^2=a^4$ so $a^2$ is idempotent and thus central. We can show that if $a^3=a$ then $(a+1)^2$ is idempotent and thus central. Then since the center of the ring is a subring, we have that $(a+1)^2-a^2-1$ is in the center so $2a$ is in the center.

The problem now asks to show that any two elements of $B$ commute; That is, if $a^3=a$ and $b^3=b$ then $ab=ba$. Haven't cracked this one yet so ideas are welcome.

Comment: (1) By "I suspect that $B$ actually induces a subring", do you mean that you think that $B$ **is** is a subring? Because any subset induces a subring -- the smallest subring that contains that subset. (2) You didn't prove that $B$ is closed under addition, because only taking multiples of individual elements is not good enough. In other words, it's not sufficient to show that $a+a\in B$ for any $a\in B$. What you need to show is that $a+b\in B$ for any $a,b\in B$. To be honest, I don't know yet whether this is true or not here; but I suspect it isn't.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3426080/a-set-of-elements-in-a-reduced-unity-ring.

Comment: @MinseonShin Good find: I knew that was there but I couldn't find it...